# Microsoft Access form - cannot add new record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am using Access 2010, and I'm trying to design a form (with fields from 3 tables).

So in design view I'm trying to create a Button and using the button wizard I'm selling the Add new record facility.

However when I click on the add button, I'm always getting the error message,

> You can't go to the specified record.  Recordest type is set as DYNASET

Recordsource SQL is as follows
SELECT PERSON.[ID CARD NO], PERSON.SURNAME, PERSON.FIRST_NAME, POLICY.POL_NO, CLAIM.CLM_NO, CLAIMLINE.TYPE, CLAIMLINE.CLM_AMT
FROM ((PERSON LEFT JOIN POLICY ON PERSON.[ID CARD NO] = POLICY.[ID CARD NO]) LEFT JOIN CLAIM ON POLICY.[POL_NO] = CLAIM.[POL_NO]) LEFT JOIN CLAIMLINE ON CLAIM.[CLM_NO] = CLAIMLINE.[CLM_NO];

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the `Record Source` property for the form. If it is just the name of a saved query then please also include the SQL SELECT statement for that query.

Comment: The form has a property setting to only allow edits to existing records, and not create new records. Check if that property is turned on.

Comment: The option to add records is on, record source updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely because of one of several reasons as mentioned here:

[Why is my query read-only?](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html)

I would narrow it down to :

1. It uses **JOINs** of different directions on multiple tables in the FROM clause. Remove some tables.
2. The fields in a JOIN are **not indexed** correctly: there is no primary key or unique index on the JOINed fields.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure you use `DYNASET` (Inconsistent Updates) if you using more than 3 tables in a query as I found from [this Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-10/aa198446(v=office.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Solved it for me, but also has good info on reasons why a query may not be updatable.