# Access Form doesn't display the add new record (empty record) - Recordsource is a View

Tags: sql-server, forms, ms-access, view

In my forms I usually have the empty line at the end of the records with which I can add a new record. Though in one of my forms I dont have this empty line.

After reading some issues about it propably has something to do with the recordsource of my form being a View (which I cant edit / add records to).

**Some background:**

My access application has linked tables and views from my SQL server. The old project was an `ADP project` and in the ADP project you always could set a `unique table` for `views` so you could add records to it.

Sadly Access 2013 doesn't have this feature and I fixed this (or at least I thought I did) by linking the views in the same way as the tables. For the Views that had to be edited (add records to it) I set primary keys to the view fields (these primary keys were the same of the primary keys of the unique table - the table on which the records getting add/edited from the view).

This seems to work since when I open the view directly in Access I can add records to it and these records also getting added in the connected table (unique table).

Though like I said before, in the form I can't add records (not manually with the empty line or with a add new record button) while I can do it directly in the view.

The following stackoverflow question: [Microsoft Access form - cannot add new record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26078367/microsoft-access-form-cannot-add-new-record) made me wonder if the provided list in the answer (http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html) is still valid / the case when you can add the records directly in the view, cause if it is it probably has something to do with my view (since it contains a `GROUP BY` which is also listed as causing it to be read only). If so, what is the problem in my view, is it only the `GROUP BY` or is it something else as well?

**The view in question:**

```
SELECT dbo.tblInkreg.becode, dbo.tblInkreg.ionummer, dbo.tblInkreg.iovolgnr, dbo.tblInkreg.ioregel, dbo.tblInkreg.arcode, dbo.tblInkreg.eenhedenbesteld, dbo.tblInkreg.eenheidbesteld, dbo.tblInkreg.aantalbesteld, 
                  dbo.tblInkreg.eenhedengeleverd, dbo.tblInkreg.eenheidgeleverd, dbo.tblInkreg.aantalgeleverd, dbo.tblInkreg.crArtNr, dbo.tblInkreg.aromschrijving, dbo.tblInkreg.stukprijs, dbo.tblInkreg.prijs, dbo.tblInkreg.irbtwcode, 
                  dbo.tblInkreg.type, dbo.tblInkreg.bocheckedtmpacc, dbo.tblInkreg.regellevdat, dbo.tblInkreg.plandat, sub.voorraad - sub.gereserveerd AS vrijevoorraad, a.arLocatie, dbo.tblInkreg.verpakbelastprijs, a.arPALocatie
FROM     dbo.tblInkreg LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.tblPLInkoop ON dbo.tblInkreg.becode = dbo.tblPLInkoop.becode AND dbo.tblInkreg.arcode = dbo.tblPLInkoop.ArCode AND dbo.tblPLInkoop.Prioriteit = 1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.tblArtikelEenheden ON dbo.tblInkreg.arcode = dbo.tblArtikelEenheden.arcode AND dbo.tblInkreg.eenheidbesteld = dbo.tblArtikelEenheden.eenheid LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      (SELECT dbo.tblArtikel.arcode, ISNULL(SUM(dbo.tblVoorraadMutaties.besteld), 0) AS inbestelling, ISNULL(SUM(dbo.tblVoorraadMutaties.voorraad), 0) AS voorraad, 
                                         ISNULL(SUM(dbo.tblVoorraadMutaties.gereserveerd), 0) AS gereserveerd
                       FROM      dbo.tblArtikel LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                         dbo.tblVoorraadMutaties ON dbo.tblArtikel.arcode = dbo.tblVoorraadMutaties.arcode
                       WHERE   (dbo.tblArtikel.isvrdart = 1)
                       GROUP BY dbo.tblArtikel.arcode) AS sub ON dbo.tblInkreg.arcode = sub.arcode LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.tblArtikel AS a ON sub.arcode = a.arcode
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the `GROUP BY` will make the query read-only.

You may not be able to remove that and still have the form to operate as you expect, so - likely - you will have to redesign your concept and how the form operates.